# Obtener registro de Datable JavaServerFaces(JSF) dando clic al registro

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf, java-ee, glassfish

Tengo una duda, tengo una <h:datable/> en JSF pero necesito eliminar un dato, haciendo clic sobre una fila par despues haciendo clic sobre un <h:commandbutton/> que diga eliminar. Pero solo debe ser un solo commandbutton, no como normalmente se hace que en cada registro de la tabla aparecen sus botones.
Se que en primefaces se puede hacer, pero en JSF normal quisiera saber. ¿Alguien sabe como?
Debe ser Javaserverfaces comun, no puedo usar primefaces ni boostfaces.
solo cuento con estas:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core
```